# How to split an NSArray into two equal pieces?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have an NSArray, and I want to split it into two equal pieces (if odd "count" then add to the latter new array) - I want to split it "down the middle" so to speak.

The following code does exactly what I want, but is there a better way?:

```
// NOTE: `NSArray testableArray` is an NSArray of objects from a class defined elsewhere;
NSMutableArray *leftArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  
NSMutableArray *rightArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i=0; i < [testableArray count]; i=i+1) {
if (i < [testableArray count]/2) {
        [leftArray addObject:[testableArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    else {
        [rightArray addObject:[testableArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}
```

Once leftArray and rightArray are made, I will not change them, so they do not need to be "mutable".  I think there may be a way to accomplish the above code with the ObjectsAtIndexes method or some fast enumeration method?, but I cannot get the following code to work (or other variations):

```
NSArray *leftArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[testableArray objectsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(????, ????)]]];
NSArray *rightArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[testableArray objectsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(????, ????)]]];
```

Does anyone know if I am going in the right direction with this or point me in the correct direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You also have the option of using `-subarrayWithRange:` detailed in the [`NSArray`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BABDBFIA) documentation:

```
NSArray *firstHalfOfArray;
NSArray *secondHalfOfArray;
NSRange someRange;

someRange.location = 0;
someRange.length = [wholeArray count] / 2;

firstHalfOfArray = [wholeArray subarrayWithRange:someRange];

someRange.location = someRange.length;
someRange.length = [wholeArray count] - someRange.length;

secondHalfOfArray = [wholeArray subarrayWithRange:someRange];
```

This method returns new, `autorelease`-d arrays.

Comment: Alex, thanks for your ultra-quick response(s)!

Your second solution is much better.  I think I got too hung up implementing NSRange, which you also laid out very clearly in the above example!

Comment: there is a bug here. There is no need to +1.
Example:
an array of 6 elements.
the first NSRange should be {0, 3}
the second NSRange should be {3, 3}. In your case you'll get an exception because the second range would be out of bounds {4, 3}.

Comment: You can do this with less lines using NSMakeRange, for example: 

    NSArray* firstHalf = [wholeArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, [wholeArray count]/2)];
    NSArray* secondHalf = [wholeArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange([wholeArray count]/2, [wholeArray count] - [wholeArray count]/2)];

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding `nil` to the end of the `-initWithObjects:` method?

```
NSArray *leftArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[testableArray objectsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(????, ????)]], nil];
NSArray *rightArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[testableArray objectsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(????, ????)]], nil];
```

Comment: Thanks, such a quick response!  I tried the above code, but I get an error related to my class, so I think I am specifying NSRange incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an extra object on first array (in case total items are odd), use following code modified from Alex's answer:

```
NSArray *arrayTotal = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", nil];
//NSArray *arrayTotal = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"B", nil];
//NSArray *arrayTotal = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C", nil];
//NSArray *arrayTotal = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", nil];
//NSArray *arrayTotal = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", nil];

NSArray *arrLeft;
NSArray *arrRight;

NSRange range;
range.location = 0;
range.length = ([arrayTotal count] % 2) ? ([arrayTotal count] / 2) + 1 : ([arrayTotal count] / 2);

arrLeft = [arrayTotal subarrayWithRange:range];

range.location = range.length;
range.length = [arrayTotal count] - range.length;

arrRight = [arrayTotal subarrayWithRange:range];

NSLog(@"Objects: %lu", (unsigned long)[arrLeft count]);
NSLog(@"%@", [arrLeft description]);

NSLog(@"Objects: %lu", (unsigned long)[arrRight count]);
NSLog(@"%@", [arrRight description]);
```