# How to split an NSMutableArray into 25 pieces

Tags: ios, iphone, nsmutablearray

I have an `NSMutableArray` with `n` entries. Is there any easy way to split this into a other `NSMutableArray`s each with 25 entries each. Value of `n` can be greater than or less than 25.

Comment: how it can be possible if array is less then 25 elements?

Comment: @AashishJoshi  If array is less than 25 element .. No need to break. We need to break array if it has count more than 25.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split an NSMutableArray into other NSMutableArrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17117339/split-an-nsmutablearray-into-other-nsmutablearrays) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768081/how-to-split-an-nsarray-into-two-equal-pieces/1768119#1768119

Comment: ok, so follow the folks link, they have searched solution for you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the below method to split your array

```
-(NSMutableArray*)splittedArrayFrom:(NSArray*)inputArray divideCount:(int)cnt
{
    NSMutableArray *mainArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    int itemsRemaining = [inputArray count];

    for (int i =0;i*cnt<[inputArray count]; i++) {
        NSRange range = NSMakeRange(i*cnt, MIN(cnt, itemsRemaining));
        NSArray *childArray = [inputArray subarrayWithRange:range];
        [mainArray addObject:childArray];
        itemsRemaining = itemsRemaining - range.length;
    }
    return mainArray;

}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6852105/1418457