# Split an NSArray into a fixed size and the rest

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsarray

I have an `NSArray` in my project which has nearly 12 elements. I want to split this array into 2 arrays. I want the first 3 elements in the first array and the rest of the elements in the second `NSArray`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [the answer of Alex Reynolds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1768119/3151675):

You should make a range that has the length of 3 and make the first half of the array with it, then modify its location and length and create the second half of the array.

```
NSArray *firstThreeArray;
NSArray *otherArray;
NSRange threeRange;

threeRange.location = 0;
threeRange.length = 3;

firstThreeArray = [wholeArray subarrayWithRange:threeRange];

threeRange.location = threeRange.length;
threeRange.length = [wholeArray count] - threeRange.length;

otherArray = [wholeArray subarrayWithRange:threeRange];
```

Comment: what if, if my array have n number of element how can i define the range of second array

Comment: This already works with every array count if the array has more than 3 elements.

Answer (score 0):

As a category of `NSArray` :

```
@implementation NSArray (NSArray_Slicing)

- (NSArray *)subarraysFromIndex:(int)index {
    return @[[self sliceToIndex:index], [self sliceFromIndex:index]];
}


- (NSArray *)sliceFromIndex:(int)index {
    NSMutableArray*mutArray = [self mutableCopy];
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(index, self.count - index);
    return [mutArray subarrayWithRange:range];
}


- (NSArray *)sliceToIndex:(int)index {
    NSMutableArray*mutArray = [self mutableCopy];
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, index);
    return [mutArray subarrayWithRange:range];
}

@end
```

And then to call it:

```
NSArray *array = @[@1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, @8, @9, @10, @11, @12];
NSLog(@"First three: %@", [array sliceToIndex:3]);
NSLog(@"Remaining:   %@", [array sliceFromIndex:3]);
NSLog(@"Sliced:      %@", [array subarraysFromIndex:3]);
NSLog(@"Original:    %@", array);
```

Comment: No need for making extra copies. `subarrayWithRange:` already creates and returns a new array.

Comment: Not necessary for demonstration purposes, but I would want to add some range checking to these methods to avoid exceptions.